# “Swift Language Version” error in an Objective C app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode9.4

Dealing with an Objective C iOS app (working fine); when I start to set some Core Data entities up, as soon as I compile I get this error message:

```
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
```

I am using Xcode Version 9.4.1 and there is no `SWIFT_VERSION` in the build settings editor.
And if I eliminate the Core Data entity I just set up, the problem goes away.

I'd be happy if someone had an explanation and told me what to do.
I am somewhat surprised to see this message related to “Swift Language Version”, when my app is only in Objective C. But I presume some dependency may be using Swift.

Comment: Please search **Swift Language Version** in Build Settings. or search only swift in Build Settings if you found any setting that related to version you can also manually write 4.1 in that.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check into your build setting about Swift version. Because I too have a project which is in Objective C but still we need to set Swift version in build setting. Please check Attached image [image]

Comment: I do not have what you have after User-Defined.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets

--> select Build setting

--> search **swift language version** (top right)

-->In Swift Language Version change version

See below screen shot.

[image]

See my updated screen shot

[image]

Comment: I only can see SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS, I do not have any "Swift Language Version", we must have a somewhat different environment.

Comment: Try to search  "swift compiler "

Comment: Actually I got in both my swift and objective c projects

Comment: Xcode Version 9.4.1. I basically can't find anything Swift.

Comment: Actually clean project, and try to remove derived data, close  Xcode and try once again

Comment: @Michel are you sure you’re in target (not project) settings?